# How do I set values for radio buttons in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-table

How do I set names for each radio button in the following PHP code using counter variable, or any other alternative?

```
<?php  

        $id=0; //counter variable 

        $sql ="select roll_number,student_name,gender from student_table";
        $query=mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

          while($post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

             echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $post['roll_number'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $post['student_name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $post['gender'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td width=250>';

            echo '<input type="radio" name="rad'.$id'" value="P" />Present';
            echo '<input type="radio" name="rad'.$id'" value="A" />Absent';

            echo '<button type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>';
            ++$id;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';               

            }

           ?>
```

Comment: does the roll_number identify the student?

Comment: try using input names as array like radio[], radio1[]

Comment: You really shouldn't use `$post` as a row-identifier. It gets confusing very fast when you also have `$_POST` for input variables.

Comment: yes roll number is unique @barudo

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie oh yea i will keep that in mind :)

Comment: And, another thing, there is not need to use that many `echo`s. Just concatinate the strings, so that would be one `echo` for all those lines.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie ok mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="rad[' . $post['roll_number'] . ']" value="P" />Present';
echo '<input type="radio" name="rad[' . $post['roll_number'] . ']" value="A" />Absent';
```

On the receiving end you may do like this:

```
$answers = $_POST['rad'];
foreach($answers as $roll_number=>$answer){
    //do something with the $roll_number and $answer...
}
```

Comment: it works now ...thanks for your time and help..very much appreciated  :D

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code, changed the `$post` to `$row`, concatenated the strings, fixed the `<button>` and so on. There is no form-declaration anywhere - if you have only one form, this will save / fetch every item in the form - depending on your needs, you might wanna declare a form per student, with a unique identifier.

```
<?php  

$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, 'SELECT roll_number,student_name,gender FROM student_table') or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['roll_number'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['gender'].'</td>
            <td width="250">
                <label><input type="radio" name="rad['.$row['roll_number'].']" value="P">Present</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="rad['.$row['roll_number'].']" value="A">Absent</label>
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
            </td>
        </tr>';
}

?>
```